# cannot display all warning message in form validation with span

Tags: php, javascript, validation

i am making a user registration form with validation.thats my simple form field.

```
<tr>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="letters"  /><span id="error" style="color:red;"></span>
<tr>

<tr>  
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="lname"  id="letters1"  /><span id="error1" style="color:red;"></span>
</tr>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

i am using a validation function on submit onsubmit="return ValidateForm();

in the validation function

```
function ValidateForm(){

    if (document.reg.fname.value=="" || !document.reg.fname.value.match(/[^\s]/))
    {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "enter first Name"
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = '';

    }

    if (document.reg.lname.value=="" || !document.reg.lname.value.match(/[^\s]/))
    {
        document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "enter last Name"
        return false;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = '';

    }
```

but for try when i submit the button..the ERROR MESSAGE shows only with first input box, and when i fill the first box then submit ..this time the error MESSAGE shows with Second text box. i am wanted to show all error message with same time.

Comment: Should probably elaborate before you get downvoted into oblivion

Comment: This is not a proper question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the return false between the tests

For a quick fix to your code I would do something like this

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/G44RH/)

```
function ValidateForm(theForm) {
    var error1 = (theForm.fname.value=="" || !theForm.fname.value.match(/[^\s]/))
    document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = (error1)?"enter first Name?":"";
    var error2 = (theForm.lname.value=="" || !theForm.lname.value.match(/[^\s]/));
    document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = (error2)?"enter last Name":"";
    return !error1 && !error2
}
```

and have

```
<form onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this)">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="letters"  /><span id="error1" style="color:red;"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>  
    <td>Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lname"  id="letters1" /><span id="error2" style="color:red;"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yay - ONE more question to get 10K rep

Answer (score 1):

That's because you use `return`, which exits the function immediately.

You should keep a variable, say `var valid` which you initially set to `true`, and when an error occurs, set it to `false` where you now use `return false`.

Then, at the end of the function, you use `return valid`.