# use multiple span error classes with single text box

Tags: javascript, validation

I put the form validation with span in my previous example
[cannot display all warning message in form validation with span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836326/cannot-display-all-warning-message-in-form-validation-with-span/7836468#7836468)

but when I use more than 1 validation on a single field then I face problem to show in span like

```
 var x=document.forms["reg"]["email"].value;
  var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
   var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
 if(x ==null || x=="")
 {
   document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = "enter Email"

   $var=false;
 }
 if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
 {
   document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "enter correct Email"
   $var=false;
 }
```

and in form field are

```
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"    /><span id="email_error" style="color:red;"></span>
                <span id="error2" style="color:red;"></span>
                <span id="error3" style="color:red;"></span></td>
```

If I use this code and leave the field blank then it shows both errors like 
"ENTER EMAIL ENTER CORRECT EMAIL". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your script is calling as soon as the page loads and there are not any values supplyed sp it runs as expected, you could place a function around it and call from for example, `form` `onsubmit`, or a inline event handler such as `onblur` on the email `input` element.

i dont know what `$var` is for but it is undeclared

try this

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"  onblur="checkEmailField()"/>
```

and the following function, this wont show "enter email" unless the user focuses on the email field then moves away from the field without entering anything.

```
function checkEmailField(){


 var x=document.forms["reg"]["email"].value;
  var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
   var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if(x ==null || x=="" )
{
  document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = "enter Email"
document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "";
   $var=false;
}else 

 if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length &&  x != "" && x!=null)
 {
 document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "enter correct Email"

 $var=false;
}
}
```

Comment: $var is a empty variable and i use to put value in this.in last of this function i check the value of $var.if is it false then i return false; else return true;

Comment: and one another problem my form is much big and have many field like in password(minimum length , space not allowed, password and re enter password matching) so how can i manage all this validation in single field with function calling on blur or other?

Comment: i can suggest a great way to get a understanding is to look at examples, i think this will be a good start , http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptform.php

Comment: ya i read this example, but my requirement is show all error message with its related field at same time,not in alert box.

Comment: @omnath this contains good info http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml

Comment: ya i used this code on first time, but its take more memory, because i need to attach this file with my website...but thanks for your precious help and time..